# Receptive field is smaller than anchor size in faster rcnn

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, caffe

I'm a little confused with the paper "Faster R-CNN: Towards Real-Time Object Detection with Region Proposal Networks". According to table1 in paper:
[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KagLL.png)
the anchor size is bigger than the receptive field of ZF net which is `171`,
and the receptive field of `VGG16` is only `228`, how can it make a accurate prediction for the anchors in size of `256×256` and `512×512`?

Is this unreasonable for the network to predict something it can't see?

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please provide some context for your question here? With context I mean share some minimal, reproducable code for your problem. Share what paper you are talking about etc pp. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I have modified my question